# Застрял с простой задачей по функции

Tags: python-3.x, функции

**Задача**

```
def fractional_part(numerator, denominator):
    # Operate with numerator and denominator to 
# keep just the fractional part of the quotient
    return 0

print(fractional_part(5, 5)) # Should be 0
print(fractional_part(5, 4)) # Should be 0.25
print(fractional_part(5, 3)) # Should be 0.66...
print(fractional_part(5, 2)) # Should be 0.5
print(fractional_part(5, 0)) # Should be 0
print(fractional_part(0, 5)) # Should be 0
```

**Решение задачи**

```
def fractional_part(numerator, denominator):
    if denominator != 0: 
        return int((numerator/denominator) - (numerator//denominator)) # Operate with numerator and denominator to 
    else:
        return 0
print(fractional_part(5, 5)) # Should be 0
print(fractional_part(5, 4)) # Should be 0.25
print(fractional_part(5, 3)) # Should be 0.66...
print(fractional_part(5, 2)) # Should be 0.5
print(fractional_part(5, 0)) # Should be 0
print(fractional_part(0, 5)) # Should be 0
```

Дает такую ошибку, что проблема в отступах, но чую, что в чем-то другом или не так?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  module test_area.py line 4
    else:
     ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Answer (score 0):

ну где-то промахнулись с отступами на строке 4

в приведённом примере все нормально в данной строке, программа работает

сам код конечно неправильный - как вы вообще хотите получить `0.25` преобразовывая данные в `int`?

```
return (numerator/denominator) - (numerator//denominator)
```

чем не устраивает? данный код выполняет ровно требуемую функцию

а можно использовать уже готовые функции для этого:

```
return math.modf(numerator/denominator)[0]
```

да и вообще все это можно в 1 строку записать

```
def fractional_part(numerator, denominator):
    return 0.0 if denominator == 0 else math.modf(numerator/denominator)[0]
```